# Why I have the method get instead of post?

Tags: python, django, post, python-requests, celery

I have a website using http and everything was working but now I update http to https protocol and I get the following problem into celery task :

```
b'{"detail":"Method \\"GET\\" no allowed."}'
```

This is my line using post :

```
requests.post('https://localhost/api/update', data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

I don't understand why I have a problem with the GET method knowing that I use POST method.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Is this related to all websites or just one particular? Can you try sending such a request to a bin at https://requestbin.com/ and confirm that the error is there as well? I suspect that the website you are calling has an issue.

Comment: It is related to only my website that I developped using Django.

Comment: Ah, then I suspect an issue with localhost and https, where you can't serve ssl stuff off the bat. Can you try sending the call like this and reporting back? `requests.post('/api/update',...`

Comment: I just tried but it does not work :/ I think the problem is the update from HTTP to HTTPS :/

Comment: I had the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the API is redirecting you.

Try the parameter

```
allow_redirects=false
```

in your request and see what happens.

Or try

```
response.history
```

for some more information.